# Product image not changing when user selects a different color

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images

I've uploaded different images for each simple product I have, depending on the color. (Not using swatches)

However, when the user selects a color from the drop down list, the product image is not changing to show the new color. Is this the default functionality? And if so, how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your can follow that [tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/create-a-color-switcher-in-magento/) to create color switcher.

or you can get free extension from magento connect

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=7&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=Color+Swatches:+Magento+Extension&t=1&p=1

Comment: Will the tutorial work if I'm not using swatches, but uploading different images for each simple product?

Comment: yes you check the tutorial it is not for swatches. it is only adding different image for each color for simple product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Plugin to solve your issue

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-switcher-free.html

Comment: It says it's not compatible with Magento 1.9 :(

Comment: you can give it a try https://github.com/wittyvishwas/Switcher